# How to design 2 different many-to-many relationships between same 2 tables with backref's / back_populate's

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

This is the situation I am trying to model:

There are `users`, which can be classified as `rider` or `driver`. Each `ride` has a `rider` and a `driver`. I can imagine working with a `ride` object, where I can call `ride.driver` or `ride.rider`. But I find it difficult to reason about it on the other direction. For any user `u`, when I call `u.rides`, it is not clear if it should return rides where `u` is the driver or the rider.

I can also seperately have two relationships, so that `u.rides_as_driver` returns rides where u is a driver and `u.rides_as_rider` to return rides where u is a rider.

Is this a good approach to model the relationship that I just described?

**Update**

If this is a good approach, how do I acheive this in SQLAlchemy? In particular, how do I use backref in this design?

What follows is my attempt:

```
class Ride:
    driver = db.Relationship('User', primaryjoin=driver_id==user.id)
    rider =  db.Relationship('User', primaryjoin=rider_id==user.id)
class User:
    rides_as_rider = db.Relationship('Ride', primaryjoin=id==ride.rider_id)
    rides_as_driver = db.Relationship('Ride', primaryjoin=id==ride.driver_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, your conclusion that you should use two `relationship`s reflects that this is not only a good way to represent this connection, ***it is the only way***

`relationship` models not the remote table, `Ride` in your case, but the connections between tables.  There are two connections between `Ride` and `User`, for the two roles each user may play in a ride.

For more evidence of this fact, notice that you also have two `relationship`'s facing away from `Ride`, toward `User`, one for each branch of the connection.  Since you have two of those, you would also require distinct backref's, one for each.

But, your code is not quite enough.  You should tell `sqlalchemy` that "this relationship is that one, only backwards".  as it is, you have four relationships, none of whom know the existence of the other.  This will manifest as mysterious effect of changes in `Ride.driver` not reflected in `User.rides_as_driver`.

The fix is easy, though, add a [`back_populates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates) to each relationship and sqlalchemy will keep them in sync:

```
class Ride:
    driver = db.Relationship('User', primaryjoin=driver_id==user.id, back_populates="rides_as_driver")
    rider =  db.Relationship('User', primaryjoin=rider_id==user.id, back_populates="rides_as_rider")
class User:
    rides_as_rider = db.Relationship('Ride', primaryjoin=id==ride.rider_id, back_populates="rider")
    rides_as_driver = db.Relationship('Ride', primaryjoin=id==ride.driver_id, back_populates="driver")
```